# Archiving and Unarchiving in Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, struct, enums, swift3, nsarchiving

I have some problems regarding **archiving** and **unarchiving** data in **swift 3.0**.

I read some posts about the same but still don't have complete clarity about some cases.

1. `enum` (I used `rawValue` to archive it.)
2. `struct` (I read about the `extension` method to archive it in http://swiftandpainless.com/nscoding-and-swift-structs/). Is there any other way to do it?
3. `Array`

Since `array` is also a `struct`, so it must also follow the archiving convention same as of a `struct`. But I am able to archive an `array` of basic data types eg. `String, Int` etc. directly. i.e.

`let arr = ["1", "2"]`, is archived directly without any `extension`.

Also, how does it work in an `array of custom objects`?

4. `Set`
5. `Dictionary`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found this solution for my struct:

```
struct Series {

var name: String?
var season: String?
var episode: String?

init(name: String?, season: String?, episode: String?) {
    self.name = name
    self.season = season
    self.episode = episode
}

static func archive(w: Series) -> Data {
    var fw = w
    return Data(bytes: &fw, count: MemoryLayout<Series>.stride)
}

static func unarchive(d: Data) -> Series {
    guard d.count == MemoryLayout<Series>.stride else {
        fatalError("Error!")
    }

    var w: Series?
    d.withUnsafeBytes({(bytes: UnsafePointer<Series>) -> Void in
        w = UnsafePointer<Series>(bytes).pointee
    })
    return w!
}
```

}

I can call the archiver like this:

```
var series = [Series]()
let arcData = Series.archive(w: series[0])
```

and the unarchiver like this:

```
var seriesItems = [Data]()
let unarcData = [Series.unarchive(d: seriesItems[0])]
```

But when I enter a name with a space the app crashes. I don't no why, because in case of season and episode there are also spaces like in "Season 1".